# Why is Div's background-color not working in nav

Tags: html, css

In this image: [image] You can see that the current state of the `nav`. The space in-between 'Search for a Website' and 'Apply for Full Access' is a `div` with id logo that has a flex-grow of 1. That `div` is supposed to be grey, but it isn't. Please help.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li href="#" >Home</li>
        <li href="#" >Search for a Website</li>
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <li href="#" >Apply for Full Access</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: min-content;
    background-color: rgb(88, 157, 172);
    padding: 0px;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 1.25em 2em;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

li:hover {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul > li:last-of-type {
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    border-right: none;
    background-color: orange;
}

div#logo {
    background-color: gray;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
    /* background-image: url(); */
}
```

Comment: BTW I know that I can solve the problem by setting the nav's background color to gray but I really want to learn why my approach isn't working.

Comment: Thats becuase you are explicitly setting the border-left to white -     border-left: 2px solid white;

Comment: The reason there is no background is because there is currently no content inside the div.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the height. When I set the height of div#logo to 4.5em instead of 100%, it worked as intended. Maybe because I set the nav height to min-content, the div inherited it and since the div has no content, it will have no height and therefore no background.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `div` has no content inside it. You will realize that `background-color` of `div` is affecting the background color of the content. Like this:

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: min-content;
    background-color: rgb(88, 157, 172);
    padding: 0px;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 1.25em 2em;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

li:hover {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul > li:last-of-type {
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    border-right: none;
    background-color: orange;
}

div#logo {
    background-color: gray;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
    /* background-image: url(); */
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li href="#" >Home</li>
        <li href="#" >Search for a Website</li>
        <div id="logo">logo</div>
        <li href="#" >Apply for Full Access</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```